# Django - voting on multiple categories in the same page/form

Tags: python, django

I recently completed Django intro tutorial, I want to create a polls app where one can vote on multiple categories on the same page/form. Everything works properly, however when I click 'vote' (ie select option and submit form) the following error keeps showing:

```
TypeError at /polls/results/

int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'QueryDict'
```

code from my *models.py:*

```
class Caty(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class Choice(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Caty, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

code from my *views.py:*

```
from django.shortcuts import get_list_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from models import Caty, Choice

def index(request):
    caty_list = Caty.objects.all()
    context = {'caty_list': caty_list} 
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)

def results(request):
    return render(request, 'polls/results.html')

def vote(request):
    caty = get_list_or_404(Caty)
    for cat in caty:
        selected_choice = cat.choice_set.get(pk=request.GET)
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
    return HttpResponse('polls:results')
```

I swapped **get_object_or_404()** in [the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial04/) with **get_list_or_404()** since I am expecting votes on multiple questions

code from my *index.html*:

```
{% if caty_list %}
    <form action="{% url 'polls:vote' %}" method="post">
    {% for caty in caty_list %}
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ caty }} <br />
        <fieldset>
        {% for choice in caty.choice_set.all %}
            <input type="radio" name="{{ caty }}" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
            <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice }}</label><br />
        {% endfor %}
        </fieldset>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Vote" />
    </form>
{% else %}
    <p>No Categories available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

I suspect my **vote()** function is poorly written, but I don't know how to fix it. Any tips or alternatives are welcomed thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `vote` method, you should pass the specific `GET` parameter containing the `pk` (using the `getlist` method since you expect a list of choices):

```
def vote(request):
    caty = get_list_or_404(Caty)
    for cat in caty:
        # Get the list of ids from the list of radio buttons
        selected_choices_pks = request.GET.getlist(caty.category_name)

        # Filter the Choices objects using theses ids
        selected_choices = Choice.objects.filter(pk__in=selected_choices_pks)

        # Increment all the filtered choices votes by 1 using the F() expression
        selected_choices.update(votes=F('votes') + 1)

return HttpResponse('polls:results')
```

Also, for you method to increment the votes by 1, I think you should use the [F()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) expression and the `update` method.
It will allow you to avoid multiple queries (loading each object, saving each object, etc.)

Comment: although this did not solve it, I got a great hint and found what was missing.Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

I swapped :

```
selected_choice = cat.choice_set.get(pk=request.GET)
```

in my **vote()** function with:

```
selected_choice = cat.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST[cat.category_name])
```

and it worked!!!